# Loop to iterate and split dataframe into chunks then write to csv

Tags: pandas, loops

I have a file imported into Pandas that I have read from csv that I need to split into chunks based upon iloc. The file has 100,000 and I want a for loop to write each of the split files to individual csv's at one time. Looking for the best way to automate this and my sample code is pasted below

```
import pandas as pd
test=pd.read_csv("test.csv")

test1=test.iloc[0:25000]
test2=test.iloc[25001:50000]
test3=test.iloc[50001:75000]
test4=test.iloc[75001:100000]

test1.to_csv("test1.csv")
test2.to_csv("test2.csv")
test3.to_csv("test3.csv")
test4.to_csv("test4.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a groupby by creating a custom index.

```
for grp, each_csv in df.groupby(df.index // 4):
    each_csv.to_csv(f"test_{grp}.csv",index=False)
```

the following dataframe would yield :

```
     A
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
10  10
```

[image]

Comment: This groupby will split your dataframe into groups of 4, not 4 groups.

Answer (score 1):

```
test=pd.read_csv("test.csv")

max_rows = 100000
page_size = 25000
current_page = 0
while current_page * page_size < max_rows:
    chunk = test.iloc[current_page * page_size: current_page * page_size + page_size - 1]
    chunk.to_csv(f"test{current_page + 1}.csv")
    current_page = current_page + 1
```

this way you just set the page size and max rows and it iterates over pages and creates a chunk for each page and saves it